# EWS API and ColdFusion: How to reference returned values

Tags: api, coldfusion, exchangewebservices

I am having difficulty working with complex arrays and could use some help.  I am working with the EWS API to integrate mail functions with Exchange 2010 and CF. The code below connects to a mailbox that the primary account has delegated authority to.  I want to return a list of messages in the inbox and work with the values that EWS returns (subject line, body, from, to, etc).

I have not worked with complex arrays like this before, so I'm confused about how to reference the values returned, specifically within the getItems() method that is returned in FindItemsResults.  I have looked a Java examples that do this same task, but I'm having trouble getting my mind wrapped around how this translates to CF.  CFDump shows that I am getting information back, so I'm confident that the connection is working as intended.  I just need to get at the data and don't know how to do it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<cfobject type="Java" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService" name="service">
<cfset service.init()>

<cfobject type="Java" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.WebCredentials" name="credentials">
<cfset credentials.init("username","password", "domain")>
<cfset service.setCredentials(credentials) />

<cfset service.AutodiscoverUrl("email@domain.com")>

<cfobject type="java" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.WellKnownFolderName" name="WellKnownFolderName">

<cfset ViewResults = service.findItems(CreateObject("java","microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.FolderId").init(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, 
CreateObject("java","microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.Mailbox").init("othermail@domain.com","SMTP")),
CreateObject("java","microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ItemView").init(3)) />

<cfdump var="#ViewResults#">

<cfdump var="#ViewResults.getItems()#">
```

[image: ViewResults.getItems() Dump Results]

Comment: What does `getItems()` return: an array, collection, ...? Can you post a screen shot of `<cfdump var="#ViewResults.getItems()#">` ?

Comment: Sorry. I tired posting one originally but couldn't due to my status. I have posted a screenshot of the dump output at [this location](http://fuzedev.com/assets/img/screen.jpg).

Comment: So it returns an array of `EmailMessage` objects. EmailMessage has a bunch of methods. Some return simple values (boolean, string) and others like `getFrom()` return complex objects. Try doing a `<cfloop array="#itemsArray#" index="message">` and inside it output one of the simple properties like: `#mesage.getIsRead()#` or `#message.getReferences()#`. If that works, try `getFrom()` which returns an [`EmailAddress`] object. Check the API, but it looks like you can access the address using either: `#message.getFrom().getAddress()#` or `#message.getFrom.get_Address()#`. (You get the idea ...)

Comment: That was the trick, Leigh. Thank you for saving countless hours of frustration! Incidentally, how to I mark this answered?

Comment: Great, glad I could help :) (I will "promote" my comment to answer then)

Answer (score 3):

(From the comments ...)

So it looks like `ViewResults.getItems()` returns an array of `EmailMessage` objects. EmailMessage has a bunch of methods. Some return simple values (boolean, string, ..) and others like `getFrom()` return complex objects.

Try doing an array loop and inside it output one of the simple properties like: `getIsRead()` or `getReferences()`. ie

```
 <cfloop array="#itemsArray#" index="message"> 
     <cfdump var="#message.getIsRead()#" label="getIsRead()">
     <cfdump var="#message.getReferences()#" label="getReferences()">
 </cfloop>
```

If that works, try calling `getFrom()` which returns an `EmailAddress` object. Check the API, but it looks like you can access the address value using either:

```
    #message.getFrom().getAddress()#  ... or 
    #message.getFrom().get_Address()#
```

(You get the idea ...)