# CFML and Exchange - CFexchange tags have stopped working

Tags: coldfusion, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, cfml

I need a little hand holding to convert my CFML cfexchange tags to the EWS API. I'm using CF 9.0.1 and need to add mail/calendar items to a hosted Exchange server.

I get the following error:

```
Error:
Could not log in to the Exchange server. 
________________________________________
connection="exchangeConn"
server="EXVMBX016-5.exch016.msoutlookonline.net"
username="exch016\j_ttt"
mailboxname="j@ttt.com"
password="[removed]"
Protocol="http"
port="80"
formbasedauthentication="TRUE"
formbasedauthenticationURL="https://owa016.msoutlookonline.net/owa/auth/logon.aspx"
```

I have come up with the following code so far;

```
<cffunction  name="EWSAddEvent" output="false" returntype="Boolean">
    <!--- EWS added by vjl  2013/10/31 --->
    <!---
        CFExchange in CF server  9  or older will not talk with Exchange 2010 at all, it is promissed to be fixed in CF 10.
        As a solution you can use the EWS API. Read the stuff below. I hope my hint is helpfull to you.
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------
        With Exchange 2007 Microsoft abandoned WebDav as an interface to Exchangeserver.
        The standard Coldfusion Tags relied on WebDav and will not work anymore.
        Since I needed a way to interface with Exchange Server a started looking for possible solutions and this is what i came up with.
        In december 2010 Microsoft released the Exchange Managed Services Library for java.
        You can find it here: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi/Release/ProjectReleases.a spx?ReleaseId=5691
        In the getting started document it tells you it depends on 4 3rd party libraries which you need to be download separately:
        -    Apache Commons HttpClient 3.1 (commons-httpclient-3.1.jar)
        -    Apache Commons Codec 1.4 (commons-codec-1.4.jar)
        -    Apache Commons Logging 1.1.1 (commons-codec-1.4.jar)
        -    JCIFS 1.3.15 (jcifs-1.3.15.jar)
        With Coldfusion 9.1 (the version I tested with) you only need
        -    JCIFS 1.3.15 (jcifs-1.3.15.jar) which you can download here: http://jcifs.samba.org/src/
        Place the EWS Jar and the JCIFS Jar in your Coldfusion libray folder and after restarting CF server the following code should work.
        If you understand this you will be able to figure out your specific needs from the EWS API documentation.
        --->
    <cfargument name="EmailAddress" type="String" required="True" />
    <cfargument name="EventName" type="String" />
    <cfargument name="EventStartDateTime" type="Date" />
    <cfargument name="EventEndDateTime" type="Date" />
    <cfargument name="EventSubject" type="String" />
    <cfargument name="EventDescription" type="String" />
    <cfargument name="EventLocation" type="String" Required="False" Default="" />
    <!--- <cfargument name="EventSensitivity" type="String" Required="False" Default="Normal" />
        <cfargument name="EventImportance" type="String" Required="False" Default="Normal" /> --->
    <cfargument name="EventReminder" type="String" Required="False" default=0 />
    <!--- <cfargument name="Organizer" type="String" Required="False" Default="" /> --->
    <cfargument name="OptionalAttendees" type="String" Required="False" Default="" />
    <cfargument name="leadID" type="numeric" required="no" default="0" />
    <cfargument name="serviceID" type="numeric" required="no" default="0" />
    <cfargument name="userID" type="numeric" required="no" default="0" />
    <cfargument name="companyID" type="numeric" required="no" default="0" />
    <cfargument name="serviceTypeID" type="numeric" required="no" default="0" />
    <cfmail to="v@g.com" from="info@t.com" subject="Exchange EWSAddEvent debug Arguments" type="html"><cfdump var="#Arguments#"></cfmail>
    <!--- Build Mailbox --->
    <cfset UserName = Left(Arguments.EmailAddress,Find("@",Arguments.EmailAddress)-1) />
    <cfset Arguments.UserName = Application.Exchange.Domain & "\" & lcase(UserName) & Application.Exchange.MailboxPostFix />
    <cfset Arguments.Pword = Trim(FetchExchangePassword(Arguments.EmailAddress)) />         
    <!--- 1. I need an instance of the ExchangeService class --->
    <cfobject type="Java" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService" name="service">
    <cfset service.init()>
    <cfmail to="v@g.c" from="info@t.com" subject="Exchange EWSAddEvent debug service" type="html"><cfdump var="#service#"></cfmail>
    <!--- 2.  I need to set the credentials --->
    <!--- 2a. Create an instance of the WebCredentials class --->
    <cfobject type="Java" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.WebCredentials" name="credentials">
    <!--- 2b. Set the credentials --->
    <cfset credentials.init("#arguments.UserName#","#Arguments.Pword#", "t.com")>
    <!--- 2c. Set the credentials in the service object --->
    <cfset service.setCredentials(credentials) />
    <!--- 3.  In need to set the URL to Exchange (stay away from autodsicovery) --->
    <!--- 3a. Create an instance of the Uri class --->
    <cfobject type="Java" class="java.net.URI" name="uri">
    <!--- 3b. Set the full path --->
    <cfset uri.init("https://mail.t.com/ews/Exchange.asmx")>
    <!--- 3c. Set the url in the service object --->
    <cfset service.setUrl(uri) />
    <!--- These are the steps you need to create valid a service object. --->
    <!--- Now we need to do something with it. --->
    <!--- I create a test message to my own mailbox to see if it works --->
    <cfobject type="Java" action="create" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.EmailMessage" name="message">
    <cfset message = message.init(service) />
    <cfset message.SetSubject("EWSTest")>
    <cfset messageBody = CreateObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.MessageBody")>
    <cfset messageBody.init("My EWS test message")>
    <cfset message.SetBody( messageBody )>
    <cfset message.ToRecipients.Add("v@t.com") >
    <cfmail to="v@g.c" from="info@t.com" subject="Exchange EWSAddEvent debug message" type="html"><cfdump var="#message#"></cfmail>
    <cfoutput>
        #message.SendAndSaveCopy()# 
    </cfoutput>
    <cfreturn True />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Nothing.  Absolutely nothing.

Comment: Well it is the weekend; I suspect most people who deal with Exchange do so as part of their job, and thus there are far fewer people willing to even look at it on fri/sat/sun. I added some tags that should give more visibility though.

Comment: Also, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652813/ews-api-and-coldfusion-how-to-reference-returned-values) appears to have working code for connecting to EWS from CF - maybe give that a try?

Comment: Oh, and the title could probably be improved to describe the question better.

Comment: Thank you.  But the code I posted gives me the error I posted.

Comment: I'm suggesting you try _other code_ that is known to succesfully connect in order to debug/isolate the issue.

Comment: What code would that be?

Comment: Oh... I see the confusion - the text "_this question_" in my earlier comment is a link to another question. Some links on SO can be hard to see if you have a high contrast screen.

Comment: I'm getting "Connection not established" in a coldfusion dump (response to call in dev tools). It'spointing to the line;

#message.SendAndSaveCopy()#

I am totally lost!

Answer (score 0):

Did you get any operation to work using EWS? Or are you facing problem when trying to send mails? If EWS itself is not working for you can you try the following snippet(Change the URL, user name and password) of code?

```
<cfscript>
service = createObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService");
service.init();
serviceURI = createObject("java", "java.net.URI");
serviceURI.init("http://10.192.37.30/ews/Exchange.asmx");
service.setUrl( serviceURI );
credentials =  createObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.WebCredentials");
credentials.init("user", "password");
service.setCredentials(credentials);
folderAPI =  createObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.Folder");

folderName =  createObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.WellKnownFolderName");

result = folderAPI.bind(service, folderName.Inbox);
writeOutput(result.getDisplayName());
```

The corresponding java code is

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
URI url = new URI( "http://10.192.37.30/ews/Exchange.asmx" );
service.setUrl( url );
service.setCredentials( new WebCredentials( "username", "password" ) );
System.out.println( "Created ExchangeService" );
Folder folder = Folder.bind( service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox );
System.out.println( folder.getDisplayName() );
```

If this works, we can try more complex operations.

Please make sure you are using the correct ASMX URL, user name and password. Try accessing the URL in the browser. Provide the user name and password. If you are able to see the WSDL, then it is fine.

Also make sure that you are using Basic Authentication in Exchange Server.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: I've been waiting all this time to get my server host (LayeredTech) to respond.  I can't ping the exchange server from my web server.  They can't seem to figure out why and what changed to cause the connection to fail.  I'll get back to you.

Comment: I completely lost track of this post.  I've started a new post on the same subject.